# Converting Dates in Shell

Tags: shell, unix, date

How can I convert one date format to another format in a shellscript?

**Example:**

the old format is

```
MM-DD-YY HH:MM
```

but I want to convert it into

```
YYYYMMDD.HHMM
```

Comment: Where do you want it to get seconds from?!

Comment: The same, BTW, goes for century, which may be actually more of an issue, because it's easier to assume 0 seconds without disturbing good night sleep with pangs of conscience :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 myDate="21-12-11 23:59"
 #fmt is DD-MM-YY HH:MM
 outDate="20${myDate:6:2}${myDate:3:2}${myDate:0:2}.${myDate:9:2}${myDate:12:2}00"

 case "${outDate}" in 
    2[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9].[0-2][0-9][0-5][[0-9][0-5][[0-9] ) 
      : nothing_date_in_correct_format 
    ;; 
    * ) echo bad format for ${outDate} >&2
    ;; 
 esac
```

Note that if you have a large file to process, then the above is an expensive(ish) process. For filebased data I would recommend something like

```
 cat infile
 ....|....|21-12-11 23:59|22-12-11 00:01| ...|

 awk '
    function reformatDate(inDate) {
       if (inDate !~ /[0-3][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][[0-9]/) {
         print "bad date format found in inDate= "inDate
         return -1
       }
       # in format assumed to be DD-MM-YY HH:MM(:SS)
       return (2000 + substr(inDate,7,2) ) substr(inDate,4,2) substr(inDate, 1,2) \
              "." substr(inDate,10,2) substr(inDate,13,2) \
               ( substr(inDate,16,2) ?  substr(inDate,16,2) : "00" )
    }
    BEGIN {       
       #add or comment out for each column of data that is a date value to convert
       # below is for example, edit as needed.
       dateCols[3]=3
       dateCols[4]=4
       # for awk people, I call this the pragmatic use of associative arrays ;-)

       #assuming pipe-delimited data for columns
       #....|....|21-12-11 23:59|22-12-11 00:01| ...|
       FS=OFS="|"
    }
    # main loop for each record
    {
       for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
         if (i in dateCols) {
            #dbg print "i=" i "\t$i=" $i
            $i=reformatDate($i)
         }
       }
       print $0
    }' infile
```

**output**

....|....|20111221.235900|20111222.000100| ...|

I hope this helps.

Comment: note slight tweak to seconds processing in awk return statement.

Answer (score 2):

Like `"20${D:6:2}${D:0:2}${D:3:2}.${D:9:2}${D:12:2}00"`, if the old date in the `$D` variable.

Comment: This is weird...could you explain this or something

Comment: but it is cool too, right!? ;-) ... To understand that code, take it apart bit-by-bit and then change 1 number at a time to see what is happening. i.e. `echo "20${D:6:2}" now change 6:2 to 6:3 or 6:1. you'll see that this is a technique for slicing up a variable by position. Good luck.

Comment: But slicing up a variable by position sounds dirty isn't there any other way to convert a date?

Comment: Eiter you date data is in the correct format or it isn't. You could build a check to make sure that the output matches a reasonable date regex, ie `case ${outDate} in 2[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-2][0-9][0-3][0-9].[0-2][0-9][0-5][[0-9] ) : nothing ;; * ) echo bad format for ${outDate}  ;; esac` . The ideal solution is to get the YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS format directly from your data source. Also, I would consider slicing a variable a feature! ;-) Good luck.

Comment: BTW: That does not even work I always get the error: 4: Bad substitution

Comment: @shellter write a post with the entire code inculding the one above and I will set this to the accepted answer ;)

Comment: @shellter: I think your case expression has one too many `[0-9]` at the start, and then the leading term of the month should be `[01]` rather than `[0-2]` (unless there are more than a dozen months in the year where you come from).  But I agree with the general approach, and there's an element of GIGO: if you give the code garbage, it will produce differently formatted garbage.  And since it won't be used on garbage, that's probably OK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : err, yes, thanks for pointing that out. MichaelPerr, I'll post an answer. MichaelKerlin-hacker, I'm upvoting your answer! Good luck to all.

Comment: Sorry I've been away from my computer all this while. Yes, there's no validation or anything of a kind in my code. Yes, shell doesn't work with dates as dates, yes, there's *a lot* of ways to manipulate and validate strings.

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of the shell's word splitting and the positional parameters:

```
date="12-31-11 23:59"
IFS=" -:"
set -- $date
echo "20$3$1$2.$4$5"  #=> 20111231.2359
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good answer down already, but you said you wanted an alternative in the comments, so here is my [rather awful in comparison] method:

```
read sourcedate < <(echo "12-13-99 23:59");
read sourceyear < <(echo $sourcedate | cut -c 7-8);
if [[ $sourceyear < 50 ]]; then
read fullsourceyear < <(echo -n 20; echo $sourceyear);
else
read fullsourceyear < <(echo -n 19; echo $sourceyear);
fi;
read newsourcedate < <(echo -n $fullsourceyear; echo -n "-"; echo -n $sourcedate | cut -c -5);
read newsourcedate < <(echo -n $newsourcedate; echo -n $sourcedate | cut -c 9-14);
read newsourcedate < <(echo -n $newsourcedate; echo :00);
date --date="$newsourcedate" +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S
```

So, the first line just reads a date in, then we get the two-digit year, then we append it to `'20'` or `'19'` based on if it's less than 50 (so this would give you years from 1950 to 2049 - feel free to shift the line). Then we append a hyphen and the month and date. Then we append a space and the time, and lastly we append `':00'` as the seconds (again feel free to make your own default). Lastly we use GNU date to read it in (since it's been standardized now) and print it in a different format (which you can edit).

It's a lot longer and uglier than cutting up the string, but having the format in the last line may be worth it. Also you could shorten it significantly with the shorthand you just learned in the first answer.

Good luck.

Comment: I sense another programming idiom besides shell is your first learning. why do you think you need to use process redirection, (i.e. `read sourcedate < <(echo "12-13-99 23:59");` to set variable values ? A much more direct solution is `sourcedate="12-13-99 23:59"`, yes? Still interesting stuff and helpful for new scriptors to see that even in the shell 'there is more than one way to do it!' :-> Good luck to all.